# How to get a bsic test list of al my bit bucket repos

Tags: text, mercurial, bitbucket

Has to be an easy way to do this 
- Just trying to pull a list of repos down from bit bucket (we use HG) in text form
We have about a zillion of the things and we need to start cleaning up

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [BitBucket REST API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs), with the [repositories endpoints](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repositories+Endpoint#repositoriesEndpoint-GETalistofrepositoriesforanaccount)

#### GET a list of repositories for an account

> Gets the list of repositories associated with an account. If the caller is properly authenticated and authorized, this method returns a collection containing public and private repositories. Otherwise, this method returns a collection of the public repositories. This produces a [paginated response](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Version+2#Version2-Pagingthroughobjectcollections).

```
GET https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{owner}
```